# where is this "(null)" coming from

Tags: c, file-io

I am trying to implement some code to pick out the last line of a text file, and am currently using this example, but I cannot figure how to prevent the code from printing out "(null)" when it cannot find the file, at the moment when it cannot find the file, it will print out "file cannot open at last line: no such file or directory" then it will print the null thing below, and for this particular application i would rather that it just print out the "file cannot open" part, but not print out the null part, if anyone could point me in the right direction for this I would really appreciate it, thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#ifndef max
#define max(a, b) ((a)>(b))? (a) : (b)
#endif

long GetFileSize(FILE *fp){
    long fsize = 0;

    fseek(fp,0,SEEK_END);
    fsize = ftell(fp);
    fseek(fp,0,SEEK_SET);//reset stream position!!

    return fsize;
}
char *lastline(char *filepath){
    FILE *fp;
    char buff[4096+1];
    int size,i;
    long fsize;
    if(NULL==(fp=fopen(filepath, "r"))){
        perror("file cannot open at lastline");
        return NULL;
    }
    fsize= -1L*GetFileSize(fp);
    if(size=fseek(fp, max(fsize, -4096L), SEEK_END)){
        perror("cannot seek");
        exit(0);
    }
    size=fread(buff, sizeof(char), 4096, fp);
    fclose(fp);
    buff[size] = '\0';
    i=size-1;
    if(buff[i]=='\n'){
        buff[i] = '\0';
    }
    while(i >=0 && buff[i] != '\n')
        --i;
    ++i;
    return strdup(&buff[i]);
}

int main(void){
    char *last;

    last = lastline("data.txt");
    printf("\"%s\"\n", last);
    free(last);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide sample input and output from your program? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add these two lines after the line `last = lastline("data.txt");`. The reason `NULL` is printed, is because you are printing the result of the function `lastline()`. This function will return `NULL` on failure.

```
if( last != NULL )
    printf( "\"%s\"\n", last );
```

Comment: By the way, note that passing a null pointer to printf for `%s` results in undefined behavior. Printing `(null)` is just one common way lots of systems handle that undefined behavior, but it's bad to rely on it even if you know you'll always be on such a system, because modern gcc tends to optimize `printf("%s\n", str);` to `puts(str);`, and the latter just crashes on null pointers.

Comment: thanks for the info, will be very helpful in the future! just starting on coding in C so am picking up as many tips as I can along the way

Answer (score 1):

It's coming from here: `printf("\"%s\"\n", last);`

```
if (last) {
  printf("\"%s\"\n", last);
  free(last);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should check the return value of [`fread`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/fread.html) to check whether it was successful. If `fread` fails then `errorno` will be set and your variable `size` won't the number of chars read. Hence, your subsequent use of the variable `buff`:

```
buff[size] = '\0';
i=size-1;
if(buff[i]=='\n'){
    buff[i] = '\0';
}
```

could produce unexpected results. So is the `strdup(buff[i])` which is returned from the function to `main`.

Comment: hello, how would you recommend that I go about changing this? relatively new to C (started teaching myself a few weeks back) so i do not have everything down perfectly yet, thanks!

Comment: Read a textbook [K & R C book](http://www.amazon.com/C-Programming-Language-2nd-Edition/dp/0131103628) is best one. Just read manuals about the functions you use. `What arguments they take`, `what they return on success/failure` etc.

Comment: Perfect, was wondering if there were any good books on C out there, will have to check that one out, thanks for your suggestion